# Como posso definir um array dentro do meu formgroup?

Tags: angular

Tenho a seguinte função que cria um form group:

Meu ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {

    //Ao iniciar a tela deve carregar o formgroup padrão das variações
    this.variacaoForm = this.fb.group({

      variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])

    });


 createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      atributo: "",
      preco: null,
      listaatributos: [{}],
      sku: '',
      tipo: '',
      id: '',
      id_produto: '',
      estoque_variacao: 0,
      linkfotovariacao: '',
      created_at: '',
      foto_prin_1: '',
      foto_prin_2: '',
      foto_prin_3: '',
      foto_prin_4: '',
      foto_prin_5: '',
      foto_prin_6: ''
    });
  }
}
```

Nessa listaatributos eu preciso que seja um array para que eu possa colocar diversos valores. Tentei adicionar em uma função esses dados que preciso que fiquem nessa listaatributos:

```
   adicionaAtributo(index: number){

   this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[index].listaatributos.push(this.idAtributo);
  }
```

No caso eu gostaria de adicionar na minha variaçaõ form na posicao informada pelo parametro aquele id de atributo. Porém quando essa função é acionada, é retornado:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'listaatributos' of undefined

Minha ideia é que eu preciso de formularios reativos, estou em um cenário que eu posso possuir mais de uma variação, e em cada variação pode ter N atributos.

a estrutura que preciso enviar para o backend seria algo como:

```
variações: [{"estoque_variacao": 900, "atributos":[12,13]}]
```

Onde nessa chave atributos eu tentei adicionar através da funçao:

```
adicionaAtributo(index: number){}
```

Comment: cria outro array dentro desse listaatributos do mesmo jeito que fez esse

Comment: poderia me explicar melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei um [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-array-reactive) que tentei simular seu exemplo.

Criei um list a parte que irá adicionar e/ou remover os itens do seu `listaatributos`, ficou assim:

```
 add(index: number, newValue) {
   this.listAtributos.push(newValue); // lista de number[]
   const control = (<FormArray>this.form.controls['variacoes']).at(index);
   control.patchValue({ listaatributos: this.listAtributos});
 }
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma:

    const control = (<FormArray>this.variacaoForm.controls['variacoes']).at(index);
    control['controls'].listaatributos.push(this.idAtributo);

Comment: mas obtive: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Comment: Não sei se te ajuda, mas minha variação form é composta dessa forma: FormGroup {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, pristine: true, touched: false, …}
asyncValidator: null
controls: {variacoes: FormArray}
dirty: (...)
disabled: (...)
enabled: (...)
errors: null
invalid: (...)
parent: (...)
pending: (...)
pristine: true
root: (...)
status: "VALID"
statusChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
value: {variacoes: Array(1)}

Comment: Consegue me dizer qual é o `console.log` da `const control ` ali?

Comment: o retorno do console.log é undefined

Comment: Criei um stackblitz e atualizei a resposta